# PDO::PARAM_* versus casting

Tags: php, types, casting, pdo

I want to know the real difference in PHP PDO between the cast variable and the constant PDO::PARAM_*

Example:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

OR

```
$stmt->bindValue(':name', (int)$name);
```

Answer (score 3):

The former method (using `PDO::PARAM_*`) means that your query will fail if `$name` doesn't match the type you specify (in this case, the `integer` type). It validates the type before it binds.

The latter (not supplying a third argument) has no such validation, so if you didn't cast `$name` as an integer, the query would still execute.